# "Theorems on factorization and primality testing" Reference request

Tags: reference-request, cryptography, prime-factorization, reference-works

I would like to ask two questions :

1. Is John M. Pollard's 1974 paper **Theorems of factorization and primality testing** available online for free ?
2. *Independently of that* : where can I find the material distilled nicely in textbook form ? Or in a nice expository paper ?

Thank you !

Comment: Pollard has a web site at https://sites.google.com/site/jmptidcott2/ . It includes a list of papers but not free copies. You may try asking him for a copy by email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pollard's 1974 paper seems to be what is described in Wikipedia under [Pollard's $p − 1$ algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm).

Try also these books:

- [Factorization and Primality Testing](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387970400) by Bressoud.
- [Primality Testing in Polynomial Time](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-3-540-40344-9) by Dietzfelbinger.
- [Primality Testing for Beginners](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=stml-70) by Rempe-Gillen and Waldecker.
- [The Joy of Factoring](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=stml-68) by Wagstaff.
- [Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387252827)
  by Crandall and Pomerance.
- [Prime Numbers and Computer Methods for Factorization](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817682972#otherversion=9780817682989) by Riesel.

See also the survey [It is easy to determine whether a given integer is prime](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-01/S0273-0979-04-01037-7/) by Granville.

Comment: Thank you for those references lhf. I think I'll try and write to Pollard directly : )

Comment: I wrote to Pollard, but unfortunately he couldn't send me his paper. I ended up buying it. I've found a copy of "The Joy of Factoring" and I'll take a look there aswell.